# Firebase cloud function on document change consecutive calls

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, backend

I have a node js cloud function in my firebase project that is triggered on every document change of type "x" which I defined, the function runs when someone using the mobile app cancels a booking so that it fills their spot from a waiting list.

Here's the issue, if 2 people cancel their booking at the exact same time, the cloud function is executed twice and fills the same person from the waiting list twice, which ends up in inconsistency and double booking.

I use firebase transactions in my code, any ideas?

[here's](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/6bx2) the code for reference

- I can't make the function disallow concurrent calls because if I exit the second trigger because the first one is still running means I lose that call
- I can't introduce a queue of operations instead of immediate handling because I need the UI to be up to date.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, [do not require the reader to use links to external information](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/more-advice#dont-require-external-and-off-site-resources). Everything should be in the question itself so future readers always have immediate access to it. If you have code, copy and paste it into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.